# Julia : getting whole path from Dijkstra function in Graphs.jl

Tags: algorithm, julia, dijkstra

Is there a possibility to acquire whole path from source vertex to destination vertex using [Dijkstra algorithm](http://graphsjl-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/algorithms.html#dijkstra-s-algorithm) from Graphs.jl module ?

There is a **update_vertex!(visitor, u, v, d)** method invoked when distance to vertex is updated. Is distance updated only when new vertex that belongs to the shortest path is found? I am not really sure.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

According to documentation there is possibility to reconstruct shortest path using [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://graphsjl-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/algorithms.html#floyd-warshall-s-algorithm) with atributes **dists** and **nexts** but I am not sure how. I would like to run it on my **GenericGraph**.

Any idea ?

Comment: Look for the `parents` field in Dijkstra algorithm result in the documentation you linked - it should enable tracking back from any vertex to a source vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the algorithm contains a field called `parents` as @DanGetz pointed out. Each of the nodes has the last node visited before arriving to it (i.e. the *parent* in the shortest path). Using the parents for each of the nodes, you can backtrack the shortest path for each of them with a simple recursive function:

```
spath(x, r, s) = x == s ? x : [spath(r.parents[x], r, s) x]
```

where `r` is the result of the Dijkstra algorithm and `s` is the source passed to it.

The shortest path for each of the nodes can be obtained by list-comprehension. Find bellow the result for the [example in the documentation](http://graphsjl-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/algorithms.html#dijkstra_shortest_paths):

```
julia> [spath(x, r, 1) for x in g.vertices]
5-element Array{Any,1}:
 1                               
  1x3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  3  2   
  1x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  3      
  1x4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  3  2  4
  1x3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  3  5
```

There are probably better algorithms to do it (i.e. some dynamic programming method to remember paths for large graphs), but as an example, the recursive method does the job.

---

A *quick* recursion code adapted to your dictionaries with multiple parents for each shortest path:

```
function spath(current, parents, source, current_path)
    if current == source || isempty(parents[current])
        return Any[[current; current_path]]
    end

    results = []
    for node in parents[current]
        results = [spath(node, parents, source, [current; current_path]); results]
    end

    results
end
```

Note the current path is passed as a parameter (copies of it) until the leaf node (source), and thus, returns the whole shortest path when it reaches it. Again, it is probably not the most efficient implementation (I'm not a julia guru) but it does the job.

For your example:

```
julia> parents = {2=>[1,3],3=>[1],1=>[]}
julia> [(i, spath(i, parents, 1, [])) for i in keys(parents)]
3-element Array{Tuple{Any,Array{Any,1}},1}:
 (2,Any[Any[1,3,2],Any[1,2]])
 (3,Any[Any[1,3]])           
 (1,Any[Any[1]])
```

Comment: This is sufficient but I had to implement my own Dijkstra because one in the **Graphs.jl** was not able to find all shortest paths e.g when between **u** an **v** exists more than one shortest path. This implementation gives in result object like in **parents** but one vertex can have multiple parents. Do you think this method can be applied to object like this ? I can post it in your answer so you can see the output of my Dijkstra.

Comment: The implementation of `Graphs.jl` will give you the shortest path between a `source` and every other node. If there are more than one shortest path with the same *cost*, it will return one of them. Why would you need *all* the shortest paths between 2 nodes? `parents` indicate the previous node in the returned shortest path, thus, backtracking will always give you a shortest path for each of the nodes (not all the shortest paths, just one, but it will have the lowest cost possible). If you need all the shortest paths between 2 nodes, then you will need to your own implementation.

Comment: @J.Jesenius to clarify again, the object `parents` in the result, are not the `parents` of each of the nodes. They are the `parents` of the shortest path. Thus, if the `parent` of `5` is `4`, means that the shortest path from `X` to `5` is through `4`. Thus, you can recursively look for the parent of `4` until you get to `X` and that way obtain the shortest path from `X` to every other node.

Comment: I am using it to determine centralities of networks. I implemented my own Dijkstra which can found all shortest paths between source and target. My algorithm returns parents field. But one vertex can have multiple parents this way. Lets assume network with **3 vertices**. Connections are **(1, 2, 1.0), (1, 3, 0.5), (2, 3, 0.5)**. My algorithm returns this **{2=>[1,3],3=>[1],1=>[]} type of: Dict{Any,Any}**

Comment: @J.Jesenius That makes sense, that implementation is just not available (to my knowledge) in Graph.jl.

Comment: Yes I implemented it only for my personal use cause I needed it. But when you can recursively get path from Graphs.jl Dijkstra parents field, can be done something like that with my parents field in the previous comment?

Comment: @J.Jesenius It can be done as well, but the recursion will be sightly more complicated, as every node needs to remember the path until it to return all the possible paths.

Comment: Yes I know, but I was looking again on what I need to accomplish and I found out that it is not needed for me to have full path, I just need to know that if there is more than one path so I have everything I need already :)

Comment: @J.Jesenius find edited a working version that returns full paths.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I think it would be great if someone implemented this in Graphs.jl package.